# Reports on dimension tables

Tags: pentaho, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I have customer dimension, that is connected to a few facts.
Sometimes, I just need to be able to retrieve some simple queries from that dimension, for example: number of customers in general, or number of male/female customers (an attribute in the customer dimension), and so on.
What is the proper way to design such a model, that will enable quering the dimensions as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Something like this for the number of male/female?

```
  SELECT
  [Measures].[Customer] ON COLUMNS,
  [Sex].[Sex].Members ON ROWS
  FROM [Database]
```

where ON ROWS are your dimensions